# I want to know how to execute json file. because It is runing in local when online it does not return any value

Tags: php, json

I want to know how to execute json file. because It is runing in local when I push the file to online it does not return any value.shall I want to give online path for xmlarr.php.
         Here is my code.INDEX.php

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function json()
    {
    alert('ok');
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        /*var url="dbarr.php";*/
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var ret_arr=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                json_arr(ret_arr);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlarr.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function json_arr(x)
    {
        var res="";
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
        //      alert(x[i].startstationname);
            res+=x[i].startstationname+" "+x[i].tostationname1+"</br>";
        }
        document.getElementById('print').innerHTML=res;
    }
    </script>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="get">
    <input type="submit" onClick="json();" value="EZEEBUS">
    </form>
    <p id="print"></p>
    my xmlarr.php

$con=mysql_connect($sname,$uname,$pwd) or die(mysql_error());
$test=mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $qry=mysql_query("select * from booking");
    echo '[';
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        echo '{"startstationname":"'.$res['stationname'].'","tostationname1":"'.$res['tostationname'].'"},';
    }
    echo '{"startstationname":"end","tostationname1":"end"}]';
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you go directly to xmlarr.php in your browser? Also, I'd highly recommend using json_encode rather than manually formatting your own JSON.

Comment: THis is the output I got.what I have to next. [{"startstationname":"Guindy","tostationname1":"Salem"},{"startstationname":"Chennai","tostationname1":"Coimbatore"},{"startstationname":"end","tostationname1":"end"}]

Comment: Is that what you get locally, or from the file online?

Comment: you can check this in my url:http://vkacademy.in/ezeebus/xmlarr.php thanks for your help

Comment: Try changing `xmlarr.php` to `/ezeebus/xmlarr.php` in `xmlhttp.open()`

Comment: I have changed the path:no response. xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.vkacademy.in/ezeebus/xmlarr.php",true);or else you can guide me how to write json encode for this.i am not familiar in this topic. thanks for your help

Comment: I have change to  xmlhttp.open("GET","/ezeebus/xmlarr.php",true); you can check with the url:http://vkacademy.in/ezeebus/ the network console is showing the value just i have given alert.but the values are not stick with the browser,moreoverxmlarr.php is also in ezeebus folder only.

Comment: thanks to every one I forgot to give return false in function json(). one final query how do I write in json_ecode for this? situation,because still now as per my knowledge i have implemented this. once again thanks for stack team..

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of the problem without asking you too much information, but here are a few things to check: (also, I added return false to your onclick handler so it doesn't change pages.)

1. Is your index.php file in the same directory as xmlarr.php?
2. Is your xmlarr.php file on the same domain as your index.php file? If not, you may be running into cross-domain restrictions. By default, you can only make AJAX requests to files that are on the same domain as the page you are currently viewing.
3. Does the network console show anything useful? In Chrome, you can open this by clicking `View` -> `Developer` -> `Developer Tools`, then clicking `Network`. After this screen is open, click your button to initiate the AJAX request and watch for an error.

Answer to edited question:

To use json_encode, you'll want to do something similar to the code below.

```
$stations = array();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $stations[] = array(
        'startstationname' => $res['stationname'],
        'tostationname1' => $res['tostationname']
    );
}

// I'm assuming this last item is no longer needed, but I added it anyway
$stations[] = array(
    'startstationname': 'end',
    'tostationname1': 'end'
);

echo json_encode($stations);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your services.one more query just you see this link http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/index.html, this is api key.they have asked me click /auth after that we need to give four paramater then it has come requrest url and response body it means the values comes with json array format as per your suggestion i use json_encode. my question is after giving four parameter in admin panel,I need to show the data by using json request url and request body.because the site is developed by codeiginter with different team my friend asked me to write the json code alone.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're wanting to use their `/auth` API and show the response from it. Since their API is hosted on a different domain, you'll most likely have to do this request in a server side language such as PHP. (They likely want you to do this anyway, assuming you're using a key.) That's outside of the scope of this question however. I'd recommend researching it a bit, then asking a new question if you still need help.